# jQuery plugin design pattern for using `this` in private methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm creating jQuery plugins using the pattern from the [Plugins Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Putting_It_All_Together) page:

```
(function($) {

   $.fn.myPlugin = function(settings) {
     var config = {'foo': 'bar'};

     if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);

     this.each(function() {
       // element-specific code here
     });

     return this;

   };

 })(jQuery);
```

My code calls for several private methods that manipulate `this`. I am calling these private methods using the `apply(this, arguments)` pattern. Is there a way of designing my plugin such that I don't have to call apply to pass `this` from method to method?

My modified plugin code looks roughly like this:

```
(function($) {

   $.fn.myPlugin = function(settings) {
     var config = {'foo': 'bar'};

     if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);

     this.each(function() {
       method1.apply(this);
     });

     return this;

   };

   function method1() {
     // do stuff with $(this)
     method2.apply(this);
   }

   function method2() {
     // do stuff with $(this), etc... 
   }

 })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) was created for these problems, though in general it does similar to what you do:

```
this.each(jQuery.proxy(method1, this));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The `jQuery.proxy` function is new to me. Isn't it simply syntactic sugar for `method1.apply()`?

Comment: @thebossman - It's an `.apply()` internally: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L689

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two ways:

1. This way more clearly but not exactly responsible for the task

   ```
   (function( $ ) {
      $.fn.myPlugin = function(settings) {
       var config = {'foo': 'bar'};

       if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);

       this.each(function() {
         method1($(this));
       });

       return this;

     };

     function method1(_this) {
       // do stuff with _this)
       alert(_this.attr('id'));
       method2(_this);
     }

     function method2(_this) {
     alert(_this.attr('customAttr'));
       // do stuff with _this, etc... 
     }
   })(jQuery);
   ```
2. This way is more extremally)))

   ```
    (function( $ ) {
      var privates = {
         method1: function() {
            // do stuff with this
            alert(this.attr('id'));
            this.method2();
         },
         method2: function () {
            alert(this.attr('customAttr'));
            // do stuff with this, etc... 
         }
       }   
       $.fn.myPlugin = function(settings) {
          var config = {'foo': 'bar'};

          if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);

          this.each(function() {
             var $this = $(this);
             $.extend($this, privates)
             $this.method1();
          });

          return this;
       };
   })(jQuery);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a scoped variable that points to this

```
(function($) {
   var me;
   $.fn.myPlugin = function(settings) {
     var config = {'foo': 'bar'};
     if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);
     me = this;
     this.each(method1);
     return this;
   };

   function method1() {
     // do stuff with me
     method2();
   }

   function method2() {
     // do stuff with me, etc... 
   }

 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: You should use `me` in those methods, not `$(me)`, `this` is already a jQuery object, it's an unnecessary clone when re-wrapping it.  I would have a read here for common mistakes like this: http://remysharp.com/2010/06/03/signs-of-a-poorly-written-jquery-plugin/

Comment: I don't use jQuery myself, its a crappy library :) But I'll update the answer